# Trying to get a Guid? via linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to get the id value from Table1 which is a Guid. This query can return a null also. So I started with following

```
Guid? SomeID = from R in Table1
    join P in Table2
    on R.Id equals P.Id2
    where R.Name == 'blah blah' 
    select R.Id;
```

But I get following compilation error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   to 'System.Guid?'

Changing Guid? to Guid didn't help.

```
Guid SomeID = from R in Table1
    join P in Table2
    on R.Id equals P.Id2
    where R.Name == 'blah blah' 
    select R.Id;
```

as now I get following error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   to 'System.Guid'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can visit this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns all matching guids and it has type `IQueryable<Guid?>`

```
IQueryable<Guid?> guids = 
    from R in Table1
    join P in Table2
    on R.Id equals P.Id2
    where R.Name == 'blah blah' 
    select R.Id;
```

If you need one guid, use `First`, `Single`, `FirstOrDefault`, or `SingleOrDefault`

```
Guild? guid = guids.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or in single statement:

```
Guid? guid = Table1.Where(R => R.Name == "blah")
                   .Join(Table2, R => R.Id, P => P.Id2, (R,P) => R.Id)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Mixed syntax (unfortunately there is no equivalent for `FirstOrDefault` operator in query syntax):

```
Guid? guid =  (from R in Table1
               join P in Table2
               on R.Id equals P.Id2
               where R.Name == 'blah blah' 
               select R.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Your code will solve this conversion problem ? I think it's a conversion problem . right ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran nope, Id is a Guid in table. There is problem in assigning `IQueryable<Guid?>` to variable of `Guid?` type

Answer (score 1):

The return value of that LINQ statement is a *list of GUIDs*. Specifically, an `IEnumerable<Guid>`.

Call `.First()` on the result of your query if you're just expecting one result, or `.FirstOrDefault()` if you might end up with no results and you just want to receive a null.

Comment: If one result is expected Single is better.

Comment: It may or may not be better to use Single. Whether getting multiple results is an exceptional circumstance completely depends on the surrounding context of this code, although the author does imply that he expects one or zero (in the case of zero, both `First` and `Single` will cause an exception).

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Select` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which is a sequence, so normally multiple items. If you want the first item use `First` or (if it can be empty) `FirstOrDefault`:

```
Guid? SomeID = (from R in Table1
               join P in Table2
               on R.Id equals P.Id2
               where R.Name == 'blah blah' 
               select R.Id).First();
```

Comment: Your code will solve this conversion problem ? I think it's a conversion problem . right ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran: I have tried to explain the issue. The linq query returns an `IEnumerable<Guid>` which is the interface that all collection types implement. So basically it is a type that is used for multiple items. But you want a single `Guid`. So you either have to change the type(f.e. `IEnumerable<Guid> ids = ....`) or you have to use `First/FirstOrDefault/Single/SingleOrDefault` to get one item.

Answer (score 0):

```
(from R in Table1
    join P in Table2
    on R.Id equals P.Id2
    where R.Name == 'blah blah' 
    select R.Id).FirstOrDefault() //or .SingleOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

IQueryable represents query for some kind of store (e.g. SQL Server) and can potentially return 0,1 or more rows. You are trying to get one of them. To get single row use methods like First/FirstOrDefault or Single/SingleOrDefult

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) or [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) or [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx), or [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method. They exist only in lambda syntax. If you expect one result use Single, if one or zero, then SingleOrDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

use `as Guid`

Look below :

```
Guid SomeID = (from R in Table1
    join P in Table2
    on R.Id equals P.Id2
    where R.Name == 'blah blah' 
    select R.Id).First() as Guid;
```

or try it

```
 Guid SomeID = (Guid) from R in Table1
        join P in Table2
        on R.Id equals P.Id2
        where R.Name == 'blah blah' 
        select R.Id).First();
```